# Wordpress + WooCommerce + Different Domains/Hoster

Tags: wordpress, dns, woocommerce, hosting, multilingual

I hope to find some help here. Imagine the following scenario:
1. Wordpress WooCommerce website is hosted by HOST-DE under domain scenario.de
2. I want to make the site multilingual (multisite or WPML-Plugin) and every language gets it´s own local hoster (for SEO reasons) and domain. (f.e. HOST-CH and scenario.ch). So the hoster only hosts the domain and get´s content from HOST-DE?
3. Is it possible to get the content from HOST-DE displayed on scenario.ch?
4. If it´s possible, how can I prevent duplicate content?

> german content only available under scenario.de and
>   swiss content only available under scenario.ch

What would you say is best practice?
Thanks in advance!
Jens

Answer (score 0):

To achieve required functionality you need to setup multisite, so each domain will represent each language.